# Why can't this thunderbolt adapter run three monitors in Ubuntu but can in Windows 10?

Tags: windows, multiple-monitors, thunderbolt

I'm using Ubuntu 18.04 and the adapter below on a dell 7490 with an i7 8th gen. Why can't ubuntu run three separate displays but Windows 10 can on the same laptop with the same adapter? Any ideas when this may be supported in the future?

[https://www.amazon.com/Adapter-Converter-Compatible-MacBook-Samsung/dp/B07QKVY23Q/](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07QKVY23Q)

Comment: Welcome metalshreds. It probably depends on the graphic driver. Sometimes a beta version will do the job while the mainstream/default won't, I already had the problem on dell+linux.

Comment: Ahh ok that makes sense, thanks! Hopefully a future update will make it work with three monitors